# Is below equation with boolean operator correct?

Tags: boolean-expression

is this correct?

**(A && X) || (B && Y) || (X && Y) = (A || X) && (B || Y)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. If `A` is true and `B` is true (with `X` and `Y` being false) then the equation reads:

```
false || false || false = true && true
```

which simplifies to:

```
false = true
```